# How to get the tfs build folder name, generated inside dropfolder while running the TFS build

Tags: tfsbuild, powershell-3.0

Created the TFS build definition and scheduled to run automatically. Also copying the build output to a drop folder at server location(\server\TFSBuildOutput).

When build runs, a separate folder is created inside drop folder(\server\TFSBuildOutput) in the format -
$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

Now i want to get the name of this newly generated folder to use in powershell script, like:

$SomePath ="D:\TFSBUildOutput\"+$newly generated folder name+ "\SomeOtherPath"

Could any one please help me for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness please see the answer:

$ENV:TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION

Using the above Team Foundation Build environment variable gives the output as

\\server-name\TFSBuildOutput\TFSBuildOutput_20150609.2

Example -
\\USTR-ERL-4608\Build Output\TBR Daily Build\TBR Daily Build_20150609.2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this while running build ? then you can pass on "droplocation" OOB variable to power shell which is available in build template.